# how to load data using query in mysql

Tags: jsp

Hi Im having trouble in loading data from mysql db to dropdown text box.

```
 <td><b>State</b></td>
<td><input class="easyui-combobox" type="text" id="state" name="state"    data-options="required:true"></input></td>


function stateCountryList() {
    var URL = serverURL + "/FormMgrWithList";
    var parameters = "requestType=StatesView&subRequestType=refreshStates&QueryNum=1848&key=STATE";
    replyFormat = getDataFromServer("POST", URL, $.deserialize(parameters), "text");
    data = eval('(' + replyFormat + ')');
    updateStatusMessage(data);
    var comboData = data.rows;
    $('#state').combobox({
        data: comboData,
        valueField: 'value',
        textField: 'text',
        cache: false,
        required: true,
        multiple: false,
        editable: false,
        onLoadSuccess: function () {
            var id = $('#state').combobox('getValue');
            var val = $(this).combobox("getData");
            if (comboData.length === 1) {
                $('#state').combobox('setValue', comboData[0].value);
            }
            $.each(val, function (i, obj) {
                if (id === obj.text) {
                    $('#state').combobox('setValue', obj.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

 select stateid as value, statename as text from state
```

In this function shows URL path and Query in parameter

Its showing deserializable is not a function.
any other types for doing this method? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think my first step would be determining where `deserializable` is defined. See if you can find out where that is and confirm you are invoking it the right way.